# Is it possible to create an int+enum in C++?

Tags: c++, enums

I am writing a program which converts postfix arithmetic expressions to infix ones using a stack. The user input is a string, which is split into an array (treating spaces as delimiters). Then a case statement for `"+"`, `"-"`, `"*"` and `"/"` distinguishes between operators and operands (i.e. if it's not one of those symbols, it's an operand; so typecast to integer).

I was wondering whether it's possible to create something similar to an `enum`, where the admissible types are either integers, or the symbols `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`?

Comment: You probably want a `Token` class that represents whatever you want.  Then either subclass it for `OperatorToken` and `NumberToken` so you can put them all on the same stack, or use something simpler like `isOperator()`, where the integer would then have the value of `OPERATOR_PLUS`, `OPERATOR_MINUS`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) -- or its doppelgänger [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic).

```
enum class Operator : char {
    plus     = '+',
    minus    = '-',
    multiply = '*',
    divide   = '/'
};

// Now a token can contain either an integer or an operator.
using Token = std::variant<int, Operator>;
```

Comment: a little enchancement can be made `enum class Operator: char`

Comment: @em2er why not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create something similar to an enum, where the admissible types are either integers

No.

An `enum` is internally a value of a C++ basic type. You cannot have integer and symbols there, except maybe if you reserve a few numbers interpreted as those symbols.

> Other alternatives

Sure: Union or struct may solve this issues.

Comment: So is it not possible to create a hybrid datatype allowing integers and only those four symbols?

Comment: No, they must be of an `Integral type` which do not includes struct or equivalent. If you have enough with 32bit integer, you may use a 64bit integer and use additional bits for this purpose.